# Modifications of chapter name in header with \fancyhdr don't work in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr, small-caps

I am formatting my headers and footers with `\fancyhdr` and for some reason all my formatting comes out fine except for `\leftmark` in the `toc` part of the document. I have tried with and without `\frontmatter`, and concocted up all manner of custom definitions for `\fancyhdr` but so far I have not hit upon the magic formula that will change `EFNISYFIRLIT` (Table of contents) in the header from all caps to small caps. The `Author` definition works fine in the `toc` part.

Small caps definition of `Author` working as expected:
[image]

And toc chapter header in all caps (where I would expect small caps):
[image]

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{%
        \thechapter.\ #1}{}}

% author definition for fancyhdr
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Author{Þórhalla Guðmundsdóttir Beck}
\let\Title\@title
\makeatother

\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\scshape\Author}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\textendash\ \thepage\ \textendash}

% redefinition of pagestyle{plain} for consistency in page number formatting
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\textendash\ \thepage\ \textendash}%
}

\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Huge}
{\scshape \oldstylenums{\thechapter}{.}}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\normalfont\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{30pt}{16pt}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{One} \lipsum[1-15] \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Two} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Three} bla \section{Stuff} bla

\chapter{Four} bla \section{Blather} bla

\chapter{Five} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{This} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Is} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Getting} bla \section{Stuff} bla

\chapter{Ridiculous} bla \section{Blather} bla

\chapter{Really} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Eitthvað} bla \section{One} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Meira} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Kjaftæði} bla \section{Stuff} bla

\chapter{Hér} bla \section{Blather} bla

\chapter{Fyrir} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Efnis} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Yfir} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\chapter{Lit} bla \section{Stuff} bla

\chapter{Andvarp} bla \section{Blather} bla

\chapter{Stuna} bla \section{Another} bla \section{Extra} bla \section{Section} bla

\begin{appendices}
\providecommand{\appendixname}{Viðauki}{\thechapter}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\itshape\huge}{\appendixname{} \thechapter.}{20pt}{\normalfont\huge}

\chapter{Alpha} bla

\chapter{Beta} bla

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `\tableofcontents` necessarily sets the left and right marks using `\MakeUppercase`; here's the formal definition from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

The easiest solution would be to redefine `\MakeUppercase` temporarily to `\scshape` (assuming it's not used elsewhere within the ToC):

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}{\scshape}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes. I was reading about \contentsname the other day. I might have realised that it wasn't using \chapter directly. But, as we say in Iceland, this swine-worked, thanks :)